# Local ring is an algebra over its residue field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that that $X$ is an algebraic variety, and $V \subset X$ is an integral subvariety.  In a paper I am trying to understand, it seems to be implicit that the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,V}$ (i.e. the stalk of $\mathcal O_X$ at the generic point of $V$) has the structure of an algebra over its residue field, which is $K(V)$.

I can't figure out how to find a copy of $K(V)$ inside $\mathcal O_{X,V}$, and my search of Hartshorne doesn't turn anything up.  Is this right?  (Everything is over $\mathbb C$, which may be relevant.)

Comment: There may be problems when the residue field is not perfect, but if you’re in char zero, it should not be hard. Sorry, I don’t have time to rack my brain for this.

Comment: I think you may have some concepts mixed up. The residue field in this case is just $\mathbb{C}$. It is the stalk modulo the maximal ideal. The stalk is in fact $K(V)$. This is a field extension of $\mathbb{C}$ because it is the fraction field of $$\mathbb{C}[x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}]/I$$ for some prime ideal $I$. There isn't a canonical way to embed $\mathbb{C}$ inside $K(V)$ but one such way exists.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh If $V$ is not a point, the residue field is not in general $\mathbb{C}$. Consider $\mathbb{A}^1\subset \mathbb{A}^2$, corresponding to $k[x,y]\to k[x]$ by $y\mapsto 0$. Then $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2,\mathbb{A}^1}=k[x,y]_{(y)}$ while $K(\mathbb{A}^1)=k(x)$. There is also a canonical way to embed $\mathbb{C}$ inside $K(V)$- as the constant functions.

Comment: @Lubin Sorry, are you saying the answer is yes in char 0?  Is there a way to extend rational functions and get an embedding $K(V) \subset \mathcal O_{X,V}$?

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh As KReiser notes, this is not true.  In general the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,V}$ has residue field $K(V)$; this is Hartshorne ex I.3.13.

Comment: Not every ring contains a coefficient field. What are the assumptions on $X$? Does your definition of a variety assume that $X$ is a finite type over complex numbers?

Comment: @Youngsu Yes, finite type over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I defer to those more knowledgeable.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the correction. I completely messed up.

Comment: Can you specify what the paper is that you are trying to understand, and where this  fact seems to be being used? For now I just make the (obvious) comment that this cannot work in a very natural way, since it is false e.g. in the mixed characteristic case.